# Trouble loading multiple versions of the same Doctrine_Record

Tags: caching, doctrine, save, version, doctrine-1.2

The following code snippet demonstrates some peculiar behaviour from Doctrine.

```
$user = Doctrine::getTable('User')->find(1);
$user->name = 'Zoppy';

// This line prevents the subsequent $user->save() from working as expected
$old_user = Doctrine::getTable('User')->find(1);

$user->save();

// Does not print 'Zoppy'
echo Doctrine::getTable('User')->find(1)->name . "\n";
```

What is going on here?

Is there some way to load the old version of a record before executing a save? It seems that Doctrine is caching something somewhere -- what exactly, and how do I turn it off! (At least temporarily.)

Answer (score 1):

I asked a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6374811/469210) recently, although I phrased it in terms of relationships.  The answer though is that this is down to the nature of caching in Doctrine.  Doctrine is keeping hydrated objects in memory.  You can `clone` the object, but as soon as you follow any relationships you'll be back to square one.