# How to make Doctrine refresh / resync bidirectional entity association?

Tags: doctrine

I have an Entity that has bidirectional ManyToOne/OneToMany relationship with another entity:

```
class BookShelf {
  /** 
  * @OneToMany(targetEntity="Book", mappedBy="shelf", cascade={"persist"})
  */
 public $books;
}
class Book {
  /** 
  * @ManyToOne(targetEntity="BookShelf", inversedBy="books", cascade={"persist"})
  */
 public $shelf;
}
```

I'm trying to create a new book, and have that object be listed in the bookshelf.

```
$book = new Book();
$book->shelf = $shelf;
$em->persist($book); $em->flush();
$shelf->showBooks();
```

After that, the `$shelf->books` does not contain the book, but instead it contains `NULL`. However the book is correctly inserted into the database, and when I run `$shelf->showBooks()` on another pageload, the book is listed properly.

I tried adding `$em->refresh($book)` and `$em->refresh($shelf)` but it doesn't help, the association still isn't refreshed.

[Doctrine manual does suggest](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/working-with-associations.html#synchronizing-bidirectional-collections) that I could use `$shelf->books->add($book)` to manually synchronize the association, but since there are initially no books, `$shelf->books` is `NULL` and I cannot call any methods on it.

**How can I make Doctrine reload the association to include the newly created associated entity?**

*(Related: ["Doctrine and unrefreshed relationships"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6374811/doctrine-and-unrefreshed-relationships))*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And as I later noticed, the *very same* Doctrine manual I linked to tells me to set the property as an ArrayCollection in the constructor, excatly so that the `$shelf->books->add($book)` *does* work. That is:

```
public function __construct() {
    $this->books = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
}
```

Stupid me. I'll post the answer here in case someone else happens to come looking for the same issue, after being just as stupid. Which is unlikely, I guess.