# Confusion with Doctrine update. (1.2.4)

Tags: doctrine-1.2

In my unit tests (on symfony 1.4), I was naively trying to edit a record to make my tests. However, I found out after some bug hunt that my script was not doing what I expected it to do. Here is the offending part:

```
$tp_vehicle = Doctrine_Core::getTable("tpVehicle")->find(10);
$tp_vehicle->setLocationId(7);
$tp_vehicle->save();
```

=> my location id has not changed whatsoever ! Whenever I do a `$tp_vehicle->getLocationId()`, I get the old value which is 8 !

So I tried this way round

```
$tp_vehicle = Doctrine_Core::getTable("tpVehicle")->find(10);
$tp_vehicle->location_id = 7;
$tp_vehicle->save();
```

And this way:

```
Doctrine_Core::getTable("tpVehicle")->createQuery("v")
                            ->update()
                            ->set("location_id", 7)
                            ->where("id = ?", 10)
                            ->execute();
```

With no luck !
In the end, I could get What I wanted with this piece of code:

```
$tp_vehicle->setLocation(Doctrine_Core::getTable("tpLocation")->find(7));
```

Which is quite awkward to me, since I really do not understand the logic that is at work behind this. I kind of have the intuition that I am missing something related to cache and doctrine optimizations but... I fail to understand exactly how this is all put together.

Can anyone shed a light on this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doctrine permits to refresh records, as mentionned in the [doc](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine1/en/latest/en/manual/component-overview.html#refreshing-records). This would go as follow:

```
$tp_vehicle->refresh();
$tp_vehicle->getLocationId();
```

See also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6374811/doctrine-and-unrefreshed-relationships) post on stack overflow.